# Joomla 4.3.3 Imported Redirects not working

Tags: joomla-4.x, redirect

more of a query than anything. I've imported some redirects using the Import option in J4 but I've just noticed that if the original page still exists, the redirect does not work.

It does say in the Joomla docs that the URL must NOT be a working one for the native Redirect plugin to work - it does not seem to have been updated for J4 however. I'm aware of how the J3 redirect plugin worked, hence why I was using ReDJ. It seems odd that J4 allows a bulk import of redirects but still ignores anywhere the source URL is still valid. It seems like a pointless function.

[Joomla Doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Help310:Components_Redirect_Manager)

I used ReDJ on my J3 sites previously but there doesn't seem to be a J4 version. I'd prefer to use an extension/plugin than manually redirect in the .htaccess as my client also creates redirects when updating the site.

Any suggestions for a J4 alternative of ReDJ? I'm open to all suggestions.

Thanks
D