# Force 404 error in J4 when php file called

Tags: joomla-4.x, overrides, redirect

this is related to my previous question regarding [native J4 redirects][1]. I'm looking at a workaround but my previous question is still valid.

I'm using [Jbusiness][2] and where previously we could redirect old business listings to new listings using ReDJ the native Redirect plugin only redirects if a 404 header is found. As my client adds the redirects when required and is not tech savvy .htaccess redirects are not really a long-term solution.

When a listing is disabled, rather than show a 404 response header Jbusiness shows a 'Listing Disabled' page. I.E. [https://bit.ly/3q7KZSK][3] so redirects no longer work.

I've created an override of the default_inactive.php from JBusiness:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package    J-BusinessDirectory
 *
 * @author     CMSJunkie http://www.cmsjunkie.com/
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2007 - 2022 CMSJunkie. All rights reserved.
 * @license    https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html
 */ 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
require_once 'header.php';
?>

<div class="item-inactive">
    <img src="<?php echo BD_PICTURES_PATH.'/item-disabled.svg' ?>">
    <div class="title"><?php echo isset($this->company->name) ? $this->escape($this->company->name) : "" ; ?></div>
    <p><?php echo JText::_("LNG_COMPANY_INACTIVE")?></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo JBusinessUtil::getWebsiteURL(true) ?>"><i class="la la-arrow-left"></i> <?php echo JText::_('LNG_GO_TO_HOMEPAGE'); ?></a>
</div>
```

Then removed `require_once 'header.php';` and replaced with

```
/*** Custom Error Page ***/
if ($this->error->getCode() == '404') {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit;
}
```

But receive a the error **Call to a member function getCode() on null**

As I'm sure you all know by now, I'm not a PHP person. I know after all these years I should really give myself a kick and get more involved with it.

I've logged a support ticket with CMS Junkie as well, I do feel this page should throw a 404 to be honest.

Kind Regards
D
[1]: [Joomla 4.3.3 Imported Redirects not working](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33209/joomla-4-3-3-imported-redirects-not-working)
[2]: https://www.cmsjunkie.com/joomla_business
[3]: https://bit.ly/3q7KZSK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw an exception with 404 error code. This should work provided the component does not catch it.

```
throw new Exception(JText::_('LNG_COMPANY_INACTIVE'), 404);
```